# CSS Content URL image is broken

Tags: css

I am trying to display images within a table cell with css. This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<td class="activity-status status_not_started">Not Started</td>
```

CSS:

```
td.activity-status {
font: 0/0 a !important;
color: transparent !important;
width: 80px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}

td.status_major_issues:after {
content: url(/sites/ih/Style%20Library/org-ih/img/status_major_issues.png) !important;
}
```

In the browser, when I visit

```
http://myspsite/sites/ih/Style%20Library/org-ih/img/status_major_issues.png
```

The image is shown just as expected.

However, in the web page after the css is applied the image appears broken.

The path to the page is:

```
http://myspsite/sites/ih/46/Pages/status.aspx
```

The path to the css file is:

```
http://myspsite/sites/ih/Style%20Library/ih-status/css/style.css
```

Anybody an idea what could be going on?

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: Show us the path of your html and css...

Comment: I've added the links to the page and to the css file.

Comment: Also, I replaced the '%20' in the css file with a blank space but that fixed the image broken but the image still doesn't show.

Comment: Have you opened up the web inspector to check what image path is actually trying to be loaded?

Comment: I see this: `td.status_major_issues::after {content: url();}`. Uhm, why does it show two colons when in the source there is only one. And, what happened to the URL?

Comment: Oh, I think that is Chrome showing the two colons by mistake.

Comment: url("../../org-ih/img/status_major_issues.png")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css is probably in a separate directory thus the path to the content should be like

```
content: url('../sites...')
```

You have to move up one directory, because the path is taken from where the css file is, not where the scripts of the page are.

Comment: Andrius, I am using an absolute URL, the double dots would then be incorrect.

Comment: You think you are using and absolute url. Yet you are not. Right click the image and check its url. Not to mention, this from you `http://myspsite/sites/ih/Style%20Library/ih-status/css/style.css` proves my point.

Comment: I see. So in css, if it doesn't contain the protocol and domain, it will be treated as a relative url.

Comment: Yes, now that I got that, I fixed the URLs and all works! :)  Thank you.